# MySQL wont accept data longer than 350 chars?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where users can submit their feedback.
Everything runs fine if their feedback is less than 60-70 words. As the feedback exceeds the limit, it throws an error.

I used this command for create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE RECORDS (ID INT NULL PRIMARY KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT, NAME VARCHAR(100), OFF VARCHAR(100), PROBLEM VARCHAR(1000));
```

If the feedback is some where around 5-10 words, it is accepted.
My PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=reports", "root", "sd22");
$dbh2 = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=sreports", "root", "sd22");
   } catch (PDOException $e) {                                 
       server_misconfig ();                                                                            }


       $log_uhashD = $dbh -> exec ("INSERT INTO `RECORDS` (`name`, `officer`, `problem`) VALUES ('$cname', '$vname', '$tarea')");
       $log_hashD = $dbh2 -> exec ("INSERT INTO `SRECORDS` (`name`, `officer`, `problem`) VALUES ('$hcname', '$hvname', '$tarea')");

    while (!$log_uhashD == '1') {
               db_logfail ();
               die();
           }
           while (!$log_hashD == '1') {
               db_logfail ();
               die();
           }


        $dbh = null;                
        $dbh2 = null;               
        JewelWrap ();
```

My form:

```
<div id="jewel-Report">
    <form action="record_report.php" method="post">
        <div id="jewel-cName"><p>Your name:&nbsp;</p>
            <input type="text" name="jewel-cName" autocomplete="off">
            <div id="jewel-vName"><p>OFF:&nbsp;</p>
                <input type="text" name="jewel-vName" autocomplete="off"></div>
                <div id="jewel-tArea"><p>Describe your problem:&nbsp;</p><textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="jewel-tArea"></textarea></div>
                <button name="jewel-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Btw, there are 2 dbs. Reports and SReports.

Comment: You did not escape the user input. That may lead to a wrong sql syntax

Comment: Umm, where's the mistake?

Comment: there are not 2 dbs, a pk cannot generally be null, and this query would produce a syntax error.

Comment: "it throws an error". What is the error? And exactly what input in the form produces that error? (Also, if you're using PDO, try using bound parameters, as that way you won't be vulnerable to the terrible SQL injection attacks that could be run with your current code.)

Comment: It's a custom error that I wrote as a function if things don't go in a proper manner.

It doesn't accept the input. If the feedback is longer than 50-60 chars, it doesn't take the input.

Comment: I sanitize the inputs before logging them into the DBs.

Comment: You should alter you code to catch the actual database error and log it, that way you'd have some clue what the problem is. Specifically, if a query fails, use [errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) on the database handle to retrieve details of the error.

Comment: I got this error:
PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's ability of holding the data. We believe that the restrictions and impositions ' at line 1 )

Comment: Apparently, It's accepting max 350 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say this is the error you get:

> I got this error: PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's ability of holding the data. We believe that the restrictions and impositions ' at line 1 )

What that indicates is that an apostrophe in the text—probably a possessive, something like "the person's ability of holding the data"—is causing your statement to be terminated.

So, the problem is what I (and juergen d) thought it was: you're actually *not* sanitising your input. You need to escape those apostrophes, otherwise the query engine will see them as closing quotes, terminating the string literal, and feeding the rest of the text in the string into the query parser as if it were SQL.

The best way would be to use [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to bind your parameters, rather than trying to splice them into the SQL statement using string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I forgot to add apostrophe to the sanitizing function! It works now!

Comment: Okay, but do *not* be writing your own sanitising functions. Sanitisation is built into PDO's parameter binding, and protection from SQL injection attacks is a lot more complicated than most people realise. It's far better to use the PDO library's built-in methods that have been developed over a long time by people who really know databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try using type **text** instead of **varchar(1000)**

```
CREATE TABLE RECORDS (ID INT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, NAME VARCHAR(100), OFF VARCHAR(100), PROBLEM TEXT);
```

Comment: @Noob: try not to use the phrase "doesn't work" anywhere if you can. It doesn't give your helper anything to go on. Firstly, try experimenting with a solution to see if you can get it to work on your own - consider answers here a starting point, rather than something that can be typed in verbatim. Also, if you really are stuck, explain *how* it didn't work. Did you get an error?

Comment: To me the above `NULL` looks wrong in the primary key - try taking that out?

Comment: Did it. Btw, no matter what datatype I used Text or Longtext, it accepts only 350 chars.

Answer (score -1):

What version of MySQL are you running, and what character set are you using?
Since MySQL4 has a different approach concerning character length it can save for special (utf8) characters.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.6.20